# How to import Turkish symbols MongoDB by mongoimport?

Tags: database, mongodb, powershell, mongoimport

I am trying to import about 90000 json files into MongoDB using mongoimport. To import I use this command in powershell: `cat *.json | mongoimport --db='myDB' --collection='myCollection'`
But in the output, instead of some characters, question marks appear.
[MongoDB doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVbXG.png)
I have changed the encoding of my powershell and it outputs the contents of files with turkish letters well. Tell me how to fix this?
[PowerShell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uav2V.png)

Comment: It is a font issue, not encoding.  Try a different font.

Comment: Why not let `mongoimport` read the file(s) directly? `mongoimport --db='myDB' --colection='myCollection' *.json`